# Universal analytics by google send event report but it not received

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I have a strange problem with google analytics. I've installed it on my site and it works fine, but when I can not track download events.

So this is my code,

```
 $('#downloadButton').on('click', function() {
              ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'Publication', title_);
            });
```

For button:

```
<a href="http://www.ict.nsc.ru/ru/Publications/publ-Principy-razrabotki-raspredelennykh-sistem-2013-1787.pdf" class="button" id="downloadButton">Download</a>
```

After click button this code works (I mean ga() function start working) and downloading of pdf file starts.

In console, when I use Google Analytics Debugger, all looks fine, but there is no reports on google-analytics dashboard:

```
    Executing Google Analytics commands. analytics_debug.js:10
Running command: ga(send, event, Download, Publication, Принципы разработки распределенных систем сбора информации на основе онтологий) analytics_debug.js:10

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j26d&a=1258098510&t=event&_s=2&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ict.nsc.ru%2Fru%2FScience%2FPublications%2Fpubl-Principy-razrabotki-ras…96230&_u=OCCCAEQE~&cid=1230919229.1407326007&tid=UA-53696329-1&z=187092433

 analytics_debug.js:10
adSenseId        (&a)   1258098510 analytics_debug.js:10
apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:10
clientId         (&cid) 1230919229.1407326007 analytics_debug.js:10
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:10
eventAction      (&ea)  Publication analytics_debug.js:10
eventCategory    (&ec)  Download analytics_debug.js:10
eventLabel       (&el)  Принципы разработки распределенных систем сбора информации на основе онтологий analytics_debug.js:10
flashVersion     (&fl)  14.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:10
hitType          (&t)   event analytics_debug.js:10
javaEnabled      (&je)  1 analytics_debug.js:10
language         (&ul)  ru analytics_debug.js:10
location         (&dl)  http://www.ict.nsc.ru/ru/Science/Publications/publ-Principy-razrabotki-raspredelennykh-sistem-2013-1787 analytics_debug.js:10
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit analytics_debug.js:10
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080 analytics_debug.js:10
title            (&dt)  Принципы разработки распределенных систем сбора информации на основе онтологий analytics_debug.js:10
trackingId       (&tid) UA-53696329-1 analytics_debug.js:10
viewportSize     (&vp)  1920x945
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Hit Callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) to make sure user is sent to download the PDF only after GA is done sending the data.

> In some cases, like when you track outbound links, you might want to know when the tracker is done sending data. That way you can send a user to their destination only after their click has been reported to Google Analytics. To solve this, the send command allows you to specify a hitCallback function in the field name object that will execute as soon as analytics.js has completed sending data. Here's how to set the hitCallback function:

```
 $('#downloadButton').on('click', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   ga('send', {
     'hitType': 'event',          
     'eventCategory': 'Download',  
     'eventAction': 'Publication',     
     'eventLabel': title_,
     'hitCallback': function () {
       window.href = $(this).attr("href");
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: I was close in my guesses and was blind, cause I've read manual twice... – Thanks a lot! And looks like I found a really strange thing when i use WebKit browsers. Chrome and Opera don't show statistics about events in real time (it show nothing), but Firefox do! Firefox shows right statistics. Anyway, thanks again=)

Comment: And my last comment was right for the Russian version of google analytics. English works perfect=)